# casting pointer to pointer to an array

Tags: c

Below is the code snippet. I want to know if `line no. 17` typecasting is valid and proper in c?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int twoInts[2];

void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
void intermediate (twoInts twoIntsAppearsByValue);

int main () {
    twoInts a;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    print(&a);
    intermediate(a);
    return 0;
}
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    print((int(*)[])b); // <<< line no. 17 <<<
}

void print(twoInts *c){
    printf("%d\n%d\n", (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);
}
```

Also, when i change the definition `intermediate` to

```
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    print(&b);
}
```

I am getting below warnings while compiling and o/p is not proper.

```
1.c:17:11: warning: passing argument 1 of print from incompatible pointer type
     print(&b);
           ^
1.c:5:6: note: expected int (*)[2] but argument is of type int **
 void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
```

As per my understanding, array is decaying to `pointer to int` in funtion argument. What is the exact reason?

Comment: Let me just add that: `void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);` is identical to: 
`void print(int (*twoIntsPtr)[2]);` Or in other words, don't hide arrays and pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: The best and proper solution to the problem, is indeed to never hide an array behind a typedef. Then you could use plain `int*`pointers without the need to obfuscate the program to oblivion.

Comment: I'd say  `print((twoInts *)&b);` should do.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is an array. So when you pass it to `intermediate()`, it gets converted into a pointer to its first element (aka "array decaying").

So, the `b` in:

```
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    print(&b);
}
```

has type `int*`, not `int[2]` as you might seem to expect. Hence, `&b` is of type `int**` rather than `int (*)[2]` that's expected by `print()` function.
Hence, the types don't match.

If you change `intermediate()` to:

```
void intermediate(twoInts *b) {
    print(b);
}
```

then you wouldn't need to pass the address of the `&b` and it will as expected and the types would match correctly.